# rendering ruby application file (game) with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, libgosu

I have a ruby file that creates a game window for me (using the gosu gem).

I am trying to render this file to a webpage.

I understand that javascript is best for doing this sort of thing but as I do not know it and am not allowed to use it for this project I'm wondering if there is any way of rendering that file directly to the webpage?

I have tried

```
    <%= render :file => '/games/game_window.rb' %>
```

but that simply renders the file as text.

Even if the method of doing this might be somewhat difficult to understand I am still interested in knowing how to do it, thank you!

Comment: Do you want to render the code inside the file, or the output of the evaluated ruby?

Comment: @joonty the file i'm trying to render creates a game window (and will eventually contain the whole game). Right now it looks like this : `require 'gosu'  
class GameWindow < Gosu::Window  
def initialize  
    super 640, 480, false  
    self.caption = "Gosu Tutorial Game"  
  end  
end  


window=GameWindow.new  
window.show` and i want that actual window to render on the html page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `gosu` gem does not create a web application, but a desktop application. You cannot simply throw the code on a browser and hope that it runs...

Currently there is [no way](http://www.libgosu.org/cgi-bin/mwf/topic_show.pl?tid=994) to run it on a web, so, no, it is not possible.

Comment: is there any ruby gem which would allow me to render it directly on a webpage?

Comment: desktop applications are totally different animals than web applications. You can't simply "render" it on a webpage. Look at the link in my answer, and see that they suggest you _might_ try to use jRuby to trick it into an applet. It is far from straight forward, and a much better solution would be to write the application you need _as_ a web application with the correct tools from scratch.

Comment: thanks so much for your help! I understand that they are different things and am new to rails, I thought since rails has the ability to render ruby it would be able to render an entire ruby file. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the html `<pre>` tag to render preformatted text, and just spit out the contents of a file with:

```
<pre><%= File.read '/games/game_window.rb' %></pre>
```

You won't be able to apply any syntax highlighting with this method, and javascript is ideal for that task. If it turns out that you can use a javascript library, I'd recommend [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/).

Comment: @UriAgassi yep that's what i'm trying to do!